# select customers with orders in Sequelize ORM

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Suppose I have the traditional database of customers and orders

I need a query that returns only those customers with orders in the Sequelize ORM

In SQL it would be something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM Customers c INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.customerId = c.id
```

But in sequelize, without raw statements, how would it be?

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

use group by

```
SELECT 
c.name,
o.customerId, 
Count(o.order_id) Number_of_Orders
FROM Customers c 
JOIN Orders o ON o.customerId = c.id
group by c.name,o.customerId,
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need the answer in the Sequelize ORM

Comment: will linq work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findAll` with the `include` option to perform a join between both `customers` and `orders` models.

```
const customersWithOrders = await Customers.findAll({
    attributes: ['name'],
    include: [{
        model: Orders,
        required: true
    }],
    group: ['Customers.name']
});
```